# Is there any way to list systemd services in linux "in-the-order-of" they were loaded?

Tags: systemd, yocto

I am trying to understand the dependencies between different systemd services in my new project. We are using yocto build system and systemd/system services.

If I perform,

> systemctl -l

It will list all the services in alphabetic order. But I am specifically looking for any commands/scripts that can be used for listing systemd services "in-the-order-of" they were loaded.

Please help.

Comment: Try `systemctl list-dependencies`. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: `systemctl list-dependencies` will not account for more subtle service startup order, the correct answer is given by shibley (`systemd-analyze plot`)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the parallel nature of the boot up process and the potentially complex dependency relationships among services, the service start up order isn't very deterministic.  However, [systemd-analyze](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html), if present on your system, can graphically plot the start up order of services:

```
systemd-analyze plot > startup_order.svg
```

It can also be used to graphically plot service dependencies:

```
systemd-analyze dot | dot -Tsvg > systemd.svg
```

Comment: Cool stuff! Congrats for the post

Comment: On dependency plot `--order --require` [might be useful](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html#Options): selects which dependencies are shown in the dependency graph.

Answer (score 3):

@shibley's tip with `systemd-analyze` is Great. Adding other helpful `systemd-analyze` commands here as I can't comment yet ...

1. Finding which service have the biggest impact on the boot time:

   ```
   systemd-analyze blame
   ```
2. Print a tree in the terminal of the service dependencies with timing impact

   ```
   systemd-analyze critical-chain
   ```